# Samsung Galaxy S I9000

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s

i have samsung galaxy S i9000..which in fact is for t-mobile (sgh t-959v). the contrast of the screen is to high really. 51% of battery drain is for the display. the brightnees i set it in lowest ..but the contrast of colours is to high. and the photos with cam or retrica are so fucked up cauze the contrast is to high not normal. please anyone can help me??